# how to build apache hive from source

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive

i have been searching a lot in the web for instructions to compile and run Apache Hive (already installed hadoop 2.6.0) but no luck - 
i tried to clone from: https://github.com/apache/hive/tree/branch-0.10
and use those compile commands: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted for hive 0.10. but it gives me errors and warning about missing all kinds of directories in the hive directory tree.
i tried more stuff but all failed.
right now i have uninstalled hadoop and want to start a fresh clean installation of hadoop+hive.

If someone can just give me directions about how to compile, what versions of hadooop/hive to use and how to configure everything i would be more than thankful.

btw: for hive it must be compiling from source. hadoop can be from a  binary package.

i have Ubutuntu 14

thanks.

Comment: What errors do you get? Could you post the errors? For hive version, try using `0.14.0` for `hadoop 2.6.0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can download sandbox VM's provided by cloudera or Hortonworks to start with. They have everything pre-installed so you can concentrate on your mapreduce or hive instead of just installing.

http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/cloudera_quickstart_vm.html